# Can't use chromedriver with Selenium after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium

My `Ubuntu` OS was upgraded from 12 to 14.04 version. Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

works perfect before upgrade, but now I get pop-up with following error:

> This computer can no longer run Google Chrome because its hardware is no longer supported

Tried to install stable `Chrome` version, but it's no use...
I still can open `Chrome` browser and run `chromedriver` server from shell, but I need to start `chromediver` with `selenium`

Comment: Cross-network dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/510019/google-chrome-no-longer-opens-after-14-04-update

Comment: @jonrsharpe, solution provided in specified ticket is to install stable `Chrome` version... I mentioned that have already tried this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by adding `/bin` folder to `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin
```

as required for using `grep` and `readlink`:

> user@LinuxServer:~/Desktop$ google-chrome -v
>
> /usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: readlink: command not found
>
> /usr/bin/google-chrome: line 15: grep: command not found